# Unwanted skips in GoogleTest

Tags: c++, googletest

I am using gtest in VS2019. I have one hundred tests in ten test suites. When I run all tests, and some tests fail, then some test suites are skipped in entirety.
I did not mark any test as skipped.
I feel that this happens when some of the fails are memory issues(invalid pointer etc). When I fix the errors and rerun, everything runs.

Why does this happen? How do I make sure every test runs when I hit "run all"?

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the way you run the test,
for that, what I suggest is create a test project file then, paste your files there and then click the build and run button the tests would open up as terminal and all tests would run, just as gtest works on linux; terminal based